# Create a service in ColdFusion

Tags: web-services, coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I have created `TestService.cfc` and make this webservice with adding remote tag.  location -  `D:\Git_Workplace\Apps\eRecruit\wwwroot`
And  created `TestRuleAction.cfc` location `D:\Git_Workplace\Apps\eRecruit\jobOffice\sys\jo\core\test\plugin`

In `TestService.cfc` 
I am creating `TestRuleAction.cfc` object and calling method `ProcessExecuteRuleActions()` which is present in `TestRuleAction.cfc` with parameter `TestExecutionID`.

[image]

In `TestRuleAction.cfc`- 
I have extended `sys.jo.core.test.plugin.abstractTestPlugin` that have `executeProcess()` method.

`executeProcess()` is responsible for executing rule and action.

I am passing `TestExecutionID` from `TestService.cfc` to `TestRuleAction.cfc` with method `ProcessExecuteRuleActions(TestExecutionID)`.
Its coming into `TestRuleAction.cfc` -> `ProcessExecuteRuleActions(TestExecutionID)`
But when I am trying to pass `TestExecutionID` in 
`getTestFactory( ).getTestExecution( arguments.TestExecutionID )`

to get testExecution object, its giving error.

[image]

I am hitting the URL from postmen
https://apracareers.localhost/testservice.cfc?method=ProcessExecuteRuleActions&TestExecutionID=924AACD4-7CC6-6D92-1112-A42A6F5C549A

Error- what I am getting-

[image]

Comment: The stack trace is reporting that the error happened in the `abstractTestPlugin.cfc` file on line 462. You did not share that code.

Comment: And the code you shared is very hard to read.